# Titanium android application development

Tags: android, image, titanium

I want to ask about the image view in titanium android development because i am not getting the right way to create a image view for my application. i have taken a window and on that i added a view with black background color and on this i want to add an image ,,at a set position but i m unable to used it....

/////here is my code//// // Add Visitor Screen by vishakha

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor:'white', height:480, width:320
}); 
win1.open(); 
var header= Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: 'black', 
    top: 0, left:0, 
    height:65, width:320
}); 
win1.add(header);
var backbutton= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'images/back.png',
    height: 40,
    top:5,
    left:5,
    width:50
}); 
header.add(backbutton);
```

but this image is not shown... n 1 thing more i put the image in resource folder... please help me ..,,hope for a example.. thanks,,

Comment: Your file path is correct if you are putting the image in `Resources/images/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the 'image' property instead of 'backgroundImage?'

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using:

```
var backbutton= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundImage:'images/back.png',
    height: 40,
    top:5,
    left:5,
    width:50
});
```

Use:

```
var backbutton= Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image:'/back.png',
    height: 40,
    top:5,
    left:5,
    width:50
});
```

That is assuming your image file is in the Resources folder. For creating an ImageView, you want to use image instead of backgroundImage.

Comment: I would have only posted the relevant line to change as the rest of the information is superfluous.